# Recursion and infinite loops problem in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, infinite-loop

I have three functions in Haskell. All of them are meant to be perform √2 based on an initial guess for n iterations.

1. ```
   squareRootTwo :: Double -> Integer -> Double
   squareRootTwo guess n
   | n == 0 = guess
   | otherwise = squareRootTwo ((guess + 2/guess) / 2) (n-1)
   ```
2. ```
   squareRootTwoA :: Double -> Integer -> Double
   squareRootTwoA guess n
   | n == 0 = guess
   | otherwise = squareRootTwoA ((guess + 2/guess) / 2) (n-1) where n=n
   ```
3. ```
   squareRootTwoB :: Double -> Integer -> Double
   squareRootTwoB guess n
   | n == 0 = guess
   | otherwise = let n = n-1 in squareRootTwoB ((guess + 2/guess) / 2) n
   ```

The first function (squareRootTwo) is working fine. In ghci:

```
ghci> squareRootTwo 1.0 5   
1.414213562373095

ghci> squareRootTwoA 1.0 5
No response
ghci> squareRootTwoB 1.0 5
No response
```

But the second and the third function aren't working at all. They just frezees. I had to press (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>) to stop this in VS Code terminal.
Now, I understand maybe it's creating a recursion and falls into a infinite loop. But, I don't understand how it's creating a infinite loop. Because the way both programs are written, to me it seems like it's not creating a infinite loop.

Since I'm new to the Haskell, I just don't understand why is this happening.

Comment: I've been out of Haskell loops for a bit, but I believe this `where n = n` is seen by the compiler the same as if you wrote `where m = m` (and replace `n-1` with `m-1`). So you basically defined a recursive "0-ary function" that is passed as second argument and when evaluated loops forever. Same in the other case `let n = n -1` defines a 0-ary function so when the recursive call evaluates it it will loop forever trying to evalute `n-1`. Basically `where` and `let` introduce a **new** variable called `n`, shadowing the argument.

Answer (score 7):

Your definitions are equivalent to the following:

```
squareRootTwoA :: Double -> Integer -> Double
squareRootTwoA guess n
  | blurb == 0  = guess
  | otherwise   = squareRootTwoA ((guess + 2/guess) / 2) (blurb-1)
 where blurb = blurb

squareRootTwoB :: Double -> Integer -> Double
squareRootTwoB guess n
  | n == 0     = guess
  | otherwise  = let blurb = blurb-1
                 in squareRootTwoB ((guess + 2/guess) / 2) blurb
```

You see that the integer argument in the recursive call has in both cases nothing at all to do with the original value `n`, it's a completely new variable that just happens to have the same name and *shadows* the old `n`. And a definition like `n = n-1` is of course circular, it's an equation that can't possibly be fulfilled (other languages are mathematically lying to you when they execute this as a statement).

The way to achieve what you attempted is to explicitly give the new version a different name:

```
squareRootTwoA :: Double -> Integer -> Double
squareRootTwoA guess n
  | n == 0     = guess
  | otherwise  = squareRootTwoA ((guess + 2/guess) / 2) (n'-1)
 where n' = n

squareRootTwoB :: Double -> Integer -> Double
squareRootTwoB guess n
  | n == 0     = guess
  | otherwise  = let n' = n-1
                 in squareRootTwoB ((guess + 2/guess) / 2) n'
```

Comment: I think you are unnecessarily harsh on other languages. Or: is Haskell lying to me when I execute `n <- return (n-1)`?

Comment: @DanielWagner `n <- return (n-1)` does not suggest that `n` and `n-1` are the same, Whereas  `n = n-1` does. Of course, all languages are ultimately just conventions; I didn't say that other languages are bad, just that they're unmathematical.

Comment: (And sure it's possible to give proper mathematical meaning to imperative languages too, but that has little in common with the syntax these languages are actually using.)

Comment: To me, getting hung up on the particular symbol used rather than the clear meaning of the notation isn't very "mathematical" either. I'll be the first to say that Haskell's mathematical nature is a huge asset when programming (I vastly prefer it to imperative). But other imperative languages (where `=` is assignment) never intended or claimed that `n = n - 1` should be read as a mathematical definition, that could therefore be called a lie. Expecting that it *should* be is exactly the same reasoning flaw the OP was making; assuming a symbol means what it would mean in some other language.

Answer (score 3):

`squareRootTwo guess n = squareRootTwo (...) (...)` is a recursive definition of `squareRootTwo`: it mentions the same name on both the left- and right-hand sides of the equals sign. `n=n-1` is a recursive definition of `n` for the same reason. There is one red herring here: you have chosen to write the equation `n=n-1` in a place where there already exists a value named `n`. This existing value is completely ignored, and that fact in itself may explain your confusion. But if not, read on.

Now, recursion isn't always a problem -- often there is a good solution to a recursive equation; for example, you gave one possible right-hand side of the `squareRootTwo` equation that works just fine despite being recursive. But I hope it is clear why `n=n-1` is a problematic recursive definition: there is no good value that `n` could be which would satisfy this equation. The result is that if you ever ask for the value of `n`, it *must* loop infinitely instead of ever returning a concrete value.

The equation `n=n` is also problematic, though it's definitely less obvious why that should be. The short version is that there are *too many* good values that `n` could be, and no good way to choose between them. So it loops infinitely.

(In general, if looping infinitely is a valid solution to a recursive equation, it is the solution that Haskell picks!)

Answer (score 0):

The problems are in the `n=n` and `n = n-1`: in both of these definitions the `n` on either side of the equals sign is the same one, so they turn into infinite loops (What is "n"? Oh, it equals "n". But what is that "n"? Oh, it equals "n". And so on until infinity.)

Solve the first case by deleting the `where n=n` part entirely, and the second one by using a new name: `n' = n - 1` and then using n' in the rest of the function body.